# How to make code indentation of JSF not show up at the beginning of the html file?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, jsf, internet-explorer-10

JSF is not doing what I would like.

Suppose I have some code such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<f:view>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h:panelGrid id="test" columns="2">
            <h:panelGrid id="test 2" columns="2">
                 <h:outputText id="content" value="Test"/>  
                 <h:outputText id="content2" value="Test"/>  
             </h:panelGrid>
             <h:panelGrid id="test 2" columns="2">
                 <h:outputText id="content3" value="Test"/>  
                 <h:outputText id="content4" value="Test"/>  
             </h:panelGrid>
         </h:panelGrid>
     </body>
 </f:view>
<html>
```

The html output has a bunch of white space in front of it. (Pretend the period are spaces.)

```
....
....
........
........
........
............
................
....................
....................
................
................
....................
....................
................
............
........
....


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Note: That the whitespace matches the indents of the JSF code.

This is a problem because too much whitespace in ie10 cause it to ignore the browser mode you put the browser into. The follow tag is ignored if you have too much whitespace in front of the doctype.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use some JSP compressing tool such as

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsp-compression/

> JSPCompression is a tool that compresses the dynamic JSP pages, by truncating unwanted spaces from the source files. it produces a very good compression with dynamic JSP pages, specially with non-HTML tags e.g. ATG tags

Comment: Interesting thought, is it a filter?

Comment: actually it really removes the spaces from the source code :-) probably something that you'd like to do only before deployment

Comment: Hmm, I don't remove want to change a lot of source.